# How to check if user exists

Tags: node.js, xmpp

How to check with xmpp node js module if user account exist on the xmpp server?

```
const Botkit = require('./node_modules/lib/botkit/lib/JabberBot.js');

var controller = Botkit({
    json_file_store: './bot_store/'
});

var bot = controller.spawn({
    client: {
        jid: botConfig.jid,
        password: botConfig.password,
        host: botConfig.host,
        port: botConfig.port
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess with a "correctly" implemented server and without special privileges, you cannot. In general it's considered to be a security flaw, if you can discover whether an account exists on a server or not. That's also what gets described within section 10.2 of RFC 6120.

For example that's also the reason why on (most) web sites the "forgot password" function will not tell you whether the user for which you requested a password recovery mail exists or not. They will only tell you something like "if the user exists, you should have gotten an e-mail".

Comment: But how to native cisco jabber (or any other jabber) client can to do search of user and add in to contact list?

Comment: @EgoBrain To search for an user, you might want to use a user directory. In that case you typically don't search for a jabber (user) id but for a name and get back the jabber id. Also typically a user directory is optional for a user, so you might not find all users there. If the user already knows the jabber id, he can just add the user to its roster without searching at all.